# How to get last used date on custom fields

Tags: custom-field

I need to do a field clean up on our org and need to produce a usage report of all custom fields with the following data:
field name,
last used date

The last used date can be the "last modified date" of the most recent record in which the field has value.
However, I need to pull such a report for all custom fields in the system, and the only way I can think of is to run SOQL query on each one of them.
Anyone has similar needs before? any better ways?

Comment: for fields with Field History Tracking enabled, you could see the last time they were updated (object-by-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LastModifiedBy field only shows when the record was updated, not specific to any field. There's no way to tell definitively the last time a field was used. Usage of [Field Trip](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4) or the like can determine if a field is frequently used, but not when it was last used. You will need to perform manual analysis to see if a field is worth keeping. I usually recommend turning off field level security for a field for a period of time and see if anyone complains about it missing.